# How to parse text and find matching string

Tags: ruby

I have a text input like this:

```
AXCGGV-102
A) some data
B) MSGH
E)Check Service MON-TUE 0515-2145 WED-THU 0515-2255
FRI 0515-2145 SAT 0645-1845 SUN 0645-2145
FINISH

AXCGKJ-103
A) some data
B) PBDR
E)Check Service MON-THU 0530-2115, FRI 0530-2000,
SAT 0730-1830, SUN 0730-2115.
FINISH
```

I want to parse this input and I want the output:

```
MSGH 0515-2145 0515-2145 0515-2255 0515-2255 0515-2145 0645-1845 0730-2115
PBDR  ..
```

in tabular format (ie. `B)` value and `E)` Mon to Sun value). I want to know how I will parse this data.

Comment: `05002000` `05002100` - where are these numbers coming from?

Comment: I have corrected the output, it is mon to sun value in E) section

Comment: `0730` `2115` - where are these numbers coming from?

Comment: Come on people, four more to go.

Answer (score 1):

In this code I assume the "`E)`" data is all on one line:

```
wday = { "MON" => 1, "TUE" => 2, "WED" => 3,
         "THU" => 4, "FRI" => 5, "SAT" => 6, "SUN" => 7 }

File.readlines('data').each { |line|
  (print $1; next) if line.match(/^B\) (\w+)/)

  next if !line.match(/^E\)\s*Check Service\s*(.*)/)

  $1.scan(/(\S+) (\d+-\d+)/).each { |days, times|
    day1, day2 = days.split '-'
    ndays = (wday[day2] || wday[day1]) - wday[day1]

    (ndays + 1).times { print " " + times }
  }

  puts
}
```

Using your sample data the output is:

```
MSGH 0515-2145 0515-2145 0515-2255 0515-2255 0515-2145 0645-1845 0645-2145
PBDR 0530-2115 0530-2115 0530-2115 0530-2115 0530-2000 0730-1830 0730-2115
```

Here's a more generic version that parses the "`E)`" line until "`FINISH`":

```
wday = { "MON" => 1, "TUE" => 2, "WED" => 3,
         "THU" => 4, "FRI" => 5, "SAT" => 6, "SUN" => 7 }

time_data = nil

File.readlines('data').each { |line|    
  if time_data
    (time_data += line; next) if !line.match(/^FINISH/)

    time_data.scan(/(\S+) (\d+-\d+)/).each { |days, times|
      day1, day2 = days.split '-'
      ndays = (wday[day2] || wday[day1]) - wday[day1]

      (ndays + 1).times { print " " + times }
    }

    time_data = nil; puts
    next
  end

  (print $1; next) if line.match(/^B\) (\w+)/)

  next if !line.match(/^E\)\s*Check Service\s*(.*)/)
  time_data = $1
}
```

Comment: This does not give the desired output.

Comment: @sawa What's wrong with the output? Times grouped mon-sun, wasn't that the desired output, or did I miss something?

Comment: Are you sure? Look carefully at what OP claimed to be the desired output.

Comment: @sawa I think the OP made a typo. Otherwise the output makes no sense whatsoever. First time poster, I think she made a mistake typing out the desired output by hand.

Comment: Yeah..sure. Not the best quality question I agree :)

Comment: "[T]he output makes no sense whatsoever." Exactly. That is why it is downvoted and closevoted. But now I see you have a different interpretation.

Comment: @sawa This worked for me, sorry for not writing the question in good way, will definitly try next time.

Comment: @casper but I have one issue as well I have the further text like this      AXCGGV-102
A) some data
B) MSGH
E)Check Service MON-TUE 0515-2145 WED-THU 0515-2255
FRI 0515-2145 SAT 0645-1845 SUN 0645-2145
FINISH

AXCGKJ-103
A) some data
B) PBDR
E)Check Service MON-THU 0530-2115, FRI 0530-2000,
SAT 0730-1830, SUN 0730-2115.
FINISH

AXCGKJ-104
A) some data
B) PBDR
E)Check Service MON-THU 0530-2115, FRI0530-2000,
SAT 0730-1830, SUN Closed.
FINISH    where  no space between days and time  FRI0530-2000 also when it is CLOSED like SUN Closed , in this case the above condition doesnt work, please help